# Existence of non-trivial solution?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c,d$ be arbitrary positive parameters. Given the following shape of $f(x)$:

$$f(x)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b\cos(x)}}-\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+d\cos(x)}}$$

Does a non-zero number $C$ exist, such that $f(x)=C$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with some specific choice of $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: It is not a functional analysis problem.

Comment: I'm happy to correct the tags if you tell me in what cathegory it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

**Hint:** Assume $f(x)\equiv C$ on $D_f$ (which is $\mathbb R$ iff $b,d<1$). Then $f'\equiv 0.$ By taking squares, $1/3$-roots etc. transform this equation to $A\cos x+B\equiv 0.$ It implies $A=B=0, b=d$ and $a=c.$ So $C=0.$

Comment: oh yes,thx.      $     $

Comment: Indeed ))      $   $ $   $

Comment: My only concern with taking $f'$ is that it gets rid of the $C$, and therefore one automatically gets the same solution as with $C=0$, which is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just had an idea. Please let me know if the following is correct.

Assume

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{g_1(x)}}-\frac{c}{\sqrt{g_2(x)}}=C$$

With abbreviations $g_1(x)=1+b\cos(x)$ and $g_2(x)=1+d\cos(x)$. Then reshape as:

$$a\sqrt{g_1(x)}-c\sqrt{g_2(x)}=C\sqrt{g_1(x)g_2(x)}$$
$$a^2g_1(x)-2ac\sqrt{g_1(x)g_2(x)}+c^2g_2(x)=C^2g_1(x)g_2(x)$$
$$4a^2c^2 g_1(x)g_2(x)=\left(a^2g_1(x)+c^2g_2(x)-C^2g_1(x)g_2(x)\right)^2$$

Finally, we realize that to have an equality, each power of $\cos(x)$ has to have the same coefficient on both sides. On the r.h.s. a term $C^2b^2d^2\cos^4(x)$ will appear, while on the l.h.s. the highest emerging power will be ~$\cos^2(x)$. Therefore, we must have $C^2b^2d^2=0$ such that the solution trivializes one way or the other.